# hydrated_bloc: Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use the hydrated_bloc package to persist a Bloc state. I already setup everything but when I try to initialize the **HydratedStorage**, I get an error saying **Null check operator used on a null value**

This is the initialization code.

```
HydratedBloc.storage = await HydratedStorage.build(
   storageDirectory: await getTemporaryDirectory(),
 );
```

This is the full stack trace

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
#0      MethodChannel.binaryMessenger
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:121
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:146
#2      MethodChannel.invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:329
#3      MethodChannelPathProvider.getApplicationDocumentsPath
package:path_provider_platform_interface/src/method_channel_path_provider.dart:50
#4      getApplicationDocumentsDirectory
package:path_provider/path_provider.dart:138
#5      main
package:main.dart:50
#6      _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:145:25)
#7      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1428:13)
#8      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
#9      _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1863:10)
#10     runZonedGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1851:12)
#11     _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure> (<…>
Reloaded 1 of 1651 libraries in 1,207ms.
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: @enzo posted already